# Como personalizar as páginas de erro em um sistema ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como exibir uma página mais amigável quando um erro ocorre em minha aplicação asp.net mvc (e não aquela página amarela)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe uma view especial para estes casos, a `Shared/Error.cshtml` (tem que ser este nome).

Basta ligar o `customErrors` de sua aplicação no *Web.config*:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

Se quiser exibir detalhes do erro, como [nome da action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo.actionname.aspx), [nome do controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo.controllername.aspx) ou a [exceção](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo.exception.aspx), você pode configurar sua view para receber um model do tipo [HandleErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo.aspx).

---

O único problema é que, infelizmente, essa solução não atende erros 404 (página não encontrada). O asp.net mvc não suporta de maneira tão fácil esse tipo de erro.

Para tratá-lo você vai precisar de uma escrever action própria para isso (uma URL própria). Exemplo, para a URL `~/erros/nao-encontrado`:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/erros/nao-encontrado" />
</customErrors>
```

Nesse caso lhe é fornecida a URL original via query string:

```
http://localhost/erros/nao-encontrado?aspxerrorpath=/administracao/algum-cadastro
```

Answer (score 2):

Em meu website eu modifiquei o Global.asax.cs e inclui

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = (MvcApplication)sender;
    var context = app.Context;
    var ex = app.Server.GetLastError();
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.ClearError();

    var httpException = ex as HttpException;

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "errors";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = ex;
    routeData.Values["action"] = "http500";

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "http404";
                break;
            case 500:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "http500";
                break;
        }
    }

    IController controller = new ErrorsController();
    controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), routeData));
}
```

E criei um `Controller` para gerenciar os erros

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Http404(Exception exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        return View(exception);
    }

    public ActionResult Http500(Exception exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        return View(exception);
    }
}
```

Desta forma se você acessar uma página inexistente você irá ser redirecionado para a Action `Http404` do Controller `Errors`.

Caso você esteja tentando acessar um item (ex: um produto) e ele não existir, você pode lançar um erro 404.

Exemplo URL: `/produtos/detalhes/10`

```
Produto x = db.GetProduto(10);

if (x == null)
    throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode criar um Error controler, retornando para a View de erro de acordo com o erro gerado

```
   public class ErrorController : Controller
     {
       //Erro 500 Servidor
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
        ViewBag.AlertaErro = "Ocorreu um Erro :(";
        ViewBag.MensagemErro = "Tente novamente ou " +
            "contate um Administrador";

        return View("Error");
    }

    //Error 404
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        ViewBag.AlertaErro = "Ocorreu um Erro :(";
        ViewBag.MensagemErro = "Não existe uma página para a URL informada";

        return View("Error");
    }


     //Erro 401 permissão de execução       
    public ActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        //ViewBag.AlertaErro = "Acesso Negado :(";
        //ViewBag.MensagemErro = "Você não tem permissão para executar isso";

        return PartialView("Error403");
    }
```

Agora no WebConfig, vc insere esse código:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="403" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Index" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
</httpErrors>
```

É bem fácil de entender, na pratica ele substitui as mensganes de erro padrão e vai passar a usar as que vc configurou na Controler